# NullValueHandling setting for a class on JSON.NET by JsonConverter attribute (for Azure DocumentDb)

Tags: c#, json, azure, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I have several DAO files, which are stored in Azure DocumentDb, and now I want that the null values won't be stored in the DocDb, it is possible by the     `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` attribute for properties. But I don't wan't to put such attribute on every property.

The problem is, there isn't any way to set the `JsonSerializerSettings` for the Json serializer used by the Azure DocumentDb API.

The way which seems for me to go, is to use the `JsonConverter` attribute on a class, and create a custom `JsonConverter` class which will use standard serialization but with changing the serialization settings.

That's the converter:

```
public class CommonJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);
        return token.ToObject(objectType, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        var jo = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer);
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

but I get on WriteJson such exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Self referencing loop detected with type
>   'Infrastructure.Dao.Contacts.PersonDao'. Path ''.

I tried to change the WriteJson function to:

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jo = JObject.FromObject(value, new JsonSerializer() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
```

but then I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it by setting the default global settings:

```
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
```