# How to ignore null fields in a customized json converter c# ?

Tags: c#, json

I need to ignore all my null  fields in my customized json converter .

My converter inherits from JsonConverter , and i've overrideed the WriteJson method.

I need to configure this setting `NullValueHandling.Ignore` for my converter ,but i can't see how to make it .

```
public class CommonJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //i dont need it now
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    var maclasse = ( Maclasse ) value ;
        writer.WritePropertyNameAndValuer("StringValue",maclasse.id);
    writer.WritePropertyNameAndValuer("StringValue",maclasse.nom);
    }
}
```

Thnak you All.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullValueHandling setting for a class on JSON.NET by JsonConverter attribute (for Azure DocumentDb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499186/nullvaluehandling-setting-for-a-class-on-json-net-by-jsonconverter-attribute-fo)

Comment: he said in his answer , to make this  JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    }; on global settings ? can you please tell me what file is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
You may use NullValueHandling setting over a base class, and inherit other classes from it.

`[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public class BaseClass{}`

Comment: Hi , i'm looking for a global solution , like applying JsonSerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling .Ignore on the converter, to avoid checking foreach property is it's null

Comment: You can try following link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: @helgarni: to inject in your code, can you please explain function 'WritePropertyNameAndValuer'? I was unable to find this method in the documentation. Nonetheless, you can use NullValueHandling in two ways, either while serializing an object https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm or with each property as an attribute https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyPropertyLevelSetting.htm

Comment: it's an extension method that i've created ,it combines WritePropertyName and WritePropertyValue

Answer (score 0):

Within an dotnet core mvc application one can call `AddJsonOptions()` after `AddMvc()` and supply it with the options to ignore `null` values within your json. However this effects all of your Json results which go through the request pipeline.

The below code can be added to your `startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // needs a reference in your `csproj` file to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json`
    services.AddJsonOptions(Startup.SetJsonOptions);
}

private static void SetJsonOptions(MvcJsonOptions options)
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomConverter());
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
}
```

For a normal console app there's something like which goes probably somewhere in your main entrypoint (application setup):

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
```

Comment: im on a web api project

Comment: The same goes for a web api project. It has a `startup.cs` class which has the above mentioned `configureservices()`. I've updated my example code to be working for a web api project. Take note of the comment to add the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json` and run a `dotnet restore`

Comment: i've added it in the webapiconfig.cs file  and it didn' work

Answer (score 0):

in `.Net 7.0` add below line into `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    })
    ;
```